# Doesn't "isin" within a lambda function work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda

Can't I use a `isin` within a lambda function. E.g.

```
mylist = ["A", "B", "C"]
df["Col2"] = df["Col1"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x.isin(mylist) else 0)
```

I'm getting an `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isin'` but the following filter works though:

```
df[df["Col1"].isin(mylist)]
```

Comment: `.isin` is a method for pandas Series, the `x` within lambda is a string, which does not have `.isin` method.

Comment: What's your question? `isin` is a `pd.Series` method. When you `apply` on a series, `x` is the value in a cell, which is string. Of course string doesn't have `.isin` method.

Comment: `df["Col2"] = df['Col1'].isin(mylist).astype(int)`

Comment: df["Col1"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x in mylist else 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `in` operator.

Replace `x.isin(mylist)` with `x in mylist` as follows:

```
df["Col2"] = df["Col1"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x in mylist else 0)
```